# Only want to display 4 divs in a row rather than 5

Tags: html

What I need is for only 4 boxes in each row with 3 rows total. Right now it's displaying 5,5,2. I had it working correctly but after adding some code I did something to mess it up. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a link to see my current code displayed. http://bakersfieldtopagents.com/zipcode-search/.

```
<style>
.title {font-size:40px; text-align:center;}
.zipcodebox { display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
.zipcodeboxxtra { display:inline; z-index:1; position:relative; margin-top:-20px; float:right; margin-right:107px; vertical-align:top;}
.zipcode {color:#FFFFFF; font-size:60px; z-index:2; position: absolute; margin-left:80px; margin-top:55px;    
-ms-transform: rotate(25deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(25deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(25deg);}
.zipcodeother {color:#FFFFFF; font-size:60px; z-index:2; position: absolute; margin-left:30px; margin-top:55px;    
-ms-transform: rotate(25deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(25deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(25deg);}
.zipcodeboximage img {height:100%; width:100%; max-height:200px; max-width:300px; padding-right:10px; padding-left:10px; z-index:1; position: relative;}
.zipcodeboxtitle {background-color:#0F0A42; color:#FFFFFF; line-height: 1; font-size: 1.6em; text-align:center; font-family: sans-serif; max-width:280px; width:100%; margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px; padding:10px;}
.zipcodeboxtitle a {color:#FFFFFF;}
.zipcodeboxtitlextra1 a {background-color:#0F0A42; color:#FFFFFF; line-height: 1; font-size: 1.6em; text-align:center; font-family: sans-serif; width:280px; padding:10px; display:block; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;}
.zipcodeboxtitlextra2 a {background-color:#0F0A42; color:#FFFFFF; line-height: 1; font-size: 1.6em; text-align:center; font-family: sans-serif; width:280px; padding:10px; display:block; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;}
.zipcodeboxtitlextra3 a {background-color:#0F0A42; color:#FFFFFF; line-height: 1; font-size: 1.6em; text-align:center; font-family: sans-serif; width:280px; padding:10px; display:block; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;}
.zipcodeboxtitlextra4 a {background-color:#0F0A42; color:#FFFFFF; line-height: 1; font-size: 1.6em; text-align:center; font-family: sans-serif; width:280px; padding:10px; display:block;}
</style>

<div class="title">Search Homes By Zipcode</div>
<center>

<div class="zipcodebox">
  <div class="zipcode">93312</div>
  <div class="zipcodeboximage"><a href=""><img src="" alt="zipcode"></a></div>
<div class="zipcodeboxtitle"><a href="">AREA TITLE</div>
</div>
<div class="zipcodebox">
 <div class="zipcode">93314</div>
  <div class="zipcodeboximage"><a href=""><img src="" alt="zipcode"></a></div>
  <div class="zipcodeboxtitle"><a href="">AREA TITLE</div>
</div>
<div class="zipcodebox">
  <div class="zipcode">93311</div>
  <div class="zipcodeboximage"><a href=""><img src="" alt="zipcode"></a></div>
  <div class="zipcodeboxtitle"><a href="">AREA TITLE</div>
</div>
<div class="zipcodebox">
  <div class="zipcode">93313</div>
  <div class="zipcodeboximage"><a href=""><img src="" alt="zipcode"></div>
  <div class="zipcodeboxtitle"><a href="">AREA TITLE</div>
</div>
<div class="zipcodebox">
  <div class="zipcode">93309</div>
  <div class="zipcodeboximage"><a href=""><img src="" alt="zipcode"></a></div>
  <div class="zipcodeboxtitle"><a href="">AREA TITLE</div>
</div>
<div class="zipcodebox">
  <div class="zipcode">93301</div>
  <div class="zipcodeboximage"><a href=""><img src=""></a></div>
  <div class="zipcodeboxtitle"><a href="">AREA TITLE</div>
</div>
<div class="zipcodebox">
  <div class="zipcode">93304</div>
  <div class="zipcodeboximage"><a href=""><img src="" alt="zipcode"></a></div>
  <div class="zipcodeboxtitle"><a href="">AREA TITLE</div>
</div>
<div class="zipcodebox">
  <div class="zipcode">93308</div>
  <div class="zipcodeboximage"><a href=""><img src="" alt="zipcode"></a></div>
  <div class="zipcodeboxtitle"><a href="">AREA TITLE</div>
</div>
<div class="zipcodebox">
  <div class="zipcode">93306</div>
  <div class="zipcodeboximage"><a href=""><img src="http://bakersfieldtopagents.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cityimage.jpg" alt="zipcode"></a></div>
  <div class="zipcodeboxtitle"><a href="">AREA TITLE</div>
</div>
<div class="zipcodebox">
  <div class="zipcode">93305</div>
  <div class="zipcodeboximage"><a href=""><img src="" alt="zipcode"></a></div>
  <div class="zipcodeboxtitle"><a href="">AREA TITLE</div>
</div>
<div class="zipcodebox">
  <div class="zipcode">93307</div>
  <div class="zipcodeboximage"><a href=""><img src="" alt="zipcode"></a></div>
  <div class="zipcodeboxtitle"><a href="">AREA TITLE</a></div>
</div>
<div class="zipcodebox">
  <div class="zipcodeother">Other Areas</div>
  <div class="zipcodeboximage"><a href=""><img src="" alt="zipcode"></a></div>
  <div class="zipcodeboxtitlextra1"><a href="">AREA TITLE</a></div>
  <div class="zipcodeboxtitlextra2"><a href="">AREA TITLE</a></div>
  <div class="zipcodeboxtitlextra3"><a href="">AREA TITLE</a></div>
  <div class="zipcodeboxtitlextra4"><a href="">AREA TITLE</a></div>
</div>
<div class="title">Search Homes By Zipcode</div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of this property set to zipcodebox class : "display:inline-block;"

Number of divs in a row will change according to the screen resolution and size.

If you want to have fixed number of divs in each row then do :

Then you need to define width of zipcodebox in percentage:
eg: width : 20%

PS: It will not be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by simply adding .container {max-width:95%;} to the css and a container div to the html. It works and is responsive.